# How to train an SVR model?

Tags: regression, svm, predictive-models, libsvm, e1071

I'm trying to figure out how SVR works, as I need to use it to model some time series.

For this purpose, before starting with this model, I've tried to create a toy-model from a sinusoidal function, with two different approaches:

- Randomly splitting the data between train and test
- Using the first 70% for training and the rest por test

Are this two approaches valid?

The first one generates a model with a high accuracy, but the second isn't predicting even the training data. Just for helping to spot the mistake, here is the code of both approaches, using R and e1071 library (I've tried also with kernlab library, with similar results). In mt first attemp I did this:

```
require(e1071)
n <- 200
x <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 20)
y <- sin (x)
plot(x,y)

trainX <- x[1:140]
trainY <- sin(trainX)
testX <- x[141:200]
testY <- sin(testX)
plot(trainX,trainY)
plot(testX,testY)

op=tune(svm, trainX,trainY,kernel="radial",ranges=list(cost=c(0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000),gamma=c(0.8,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1)))
fit = op$best.model
summary(fit)
pred=predict(fit,testX)
plot(testX,testY)
points(testX,pred, col = "red", pch=4)
```

With this result:

[image: Results with randomized train and test]

Here is the code for the second one:

```
require(e1071)
x <- seq(0,199.9,0.1)
f <- sin (x)
train <- data.frame(time = x[1:1400],y = f[1:1400])
#train <- train[sample(nrow(train)),] # Shuffle data. Not needed?
test <- data.frame(time = x[1401:2000],y = f[1401:2000])
plot(train)
plot(test)
#op=tune.svm (train$time, train$y, data=train,gamma=seq(0.01,1.1,0.3),cost=0.000001*10^(0:2))
op=tune(svm, train$time, train$y, kernel="radial",ranges=list(cost=c(0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000),gamma=c(0.8,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1)))
fit = op$best.model
summary(fit)
pred<- predict(fit,test$time)
plot(test)
points(test$time,pred, col = "red", pch=4)
```

But the result is clearly wrong:

[image: Second attemp, wrong result]

Do you have any clue about what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, let me know if you still think my question is off-topic after the changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your second example you are using only very small values for c in grid search: (`(0.000001,0.00001,0.0001)`) Low values of `c` in SVM imply strict regularization. The results you get may be due to extreme underfitting. Try using the same parameters for grid search as in the first example and check whether the parameter estimates for your op$best.model are close to zero.

Comment: I shortened the list to acelerate the code, but is true I've chose the wrong ones (I'm going to edit that on my question)... Trying with the same list as in the first example, the result is the same... It even fails predicting the train values!